# pandas dataframe style numbers to currency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a simple dataframe that contains Dates as columns and numbers as row values. I am attempting to add formatting to the numbers so that they display in currency format of $x.xx.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong as no error is produced and all the other formats I have are being applied except for the currency formatting.  Below is a snippet of the code in question.

```
format_df = final_df.style.        apply(lambda row: ['background-color: yellow'
                         if row.name in team_totals_index else 'background-color:#FFCC99' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['${:,.2f}' if row.name in team_totals_index else '' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['font-weight: bold' if row.name in team_totals_index else '' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['border-top-style:solid' if row.name in team_totals_index else '' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['border-bottom-style:solid' if row.name in team_totals_index else '' for value in row], axis=1)
```

[here's an image of the excel sheet it produces, the bold, border, and colors show but not the currency format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7P1d.png)

any insight on how I could fix this so that the currency format will reflect properly?

Answer (score 2):

after looking through the official documentation I stumbled upon "number-format" which allowed me to add the currency format I was looking for.

[here's an image from the docs showing what is acceptable when writing to excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvVND.png)

in case anyone is curious, I modified my code to the below:

```
    #style the dataframe totals in bold/border and highlight background colors
    format_df = final_df.style.        apply(lambda row: ['background-color: #FF9900'
                         if row.name in team_totals_index else 'background-color:#FFCC99' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['number-format: $#,##0.00' if row.name in team_totals_index else 'number-format: $#,##0.00' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['font-weight: bold' if row.name in team_totals_index else '' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['border-top-style:solid' if row.name in team_totals_index else '' for value in row], axis=1).\
        apply(lambda row: ['border-bottom-style:solid' if row.name in team_totals_index else '' for value in row], axis=1)
    
    return format_df
```

This has yielded the results I was looking for.

[excel sheet with the proper formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9GEV.png)